# Grid content priority in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to make piano-like layout using Grid in Xamarin.Forms. Looks fine but because of using RowSpan when I press one of my white buttons, it corrupts visibility of the black button near to it.
[Example pressing button "D"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVXyp.png)
I tried to fix this by focusing to the "corrupted" black button when the white one is pressed but it didn't solve anything. I'd appreciate any tip.
Here's a part of my XAML:

```
<Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="Grid.RowSpan" Value="3"/>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="3"/>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <!--white buttons-->
        <Button x:Name="C" Text="C" Grid.Column="0" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
        <Button x:Name="D" Text="D" Grid.Column="3" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
        <Button x:Name="E" Text="E" Grid.Column="6" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
        <Button x:Name="F" Text="F" Grid.Column="9" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
        <Button x:Name="G" Text="G" Grid.Column="12" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
        <Button x:Name="A" Text="A" Grid.Column="15" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
        <Button x:Name="H" Text="H" Grid.Column="18" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
        <!--black buttons-->
        <Button x:Name="Cis" Text="Cis" BackgroundColor="Black" TextColor="White" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="1" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
        <Button x:Name="Dis" Text="Dis" BackgroundColor="Black" TextColor="White" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="1" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
        <Button x:Name="Fis" Text="Fis" BackgroundColor="Black" TextColor="White" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="11" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="1" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
        <Button x:Name="Gis" Text="Gis" BackgroundColor="Black" TextColor="White" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="14" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="1" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
        <Button x:Name="Ais" Text="Ais" BackgroundColor="Black" TextColor="White" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="17" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="1" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
```

Comment: I think I'd try separating the black and white keys into separate grids

Comment: Tried this but having two exactly the same grids in the same place, I'm only able to play only white or only black keys (depends whats written later)

Comment: align them next to each other, not on top of one another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by [Xamarin.Forms Fast Renderers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/internals/fast-renderers):

From `Xamarin.Forms 4.0` onwards, all applications targeting `FormsAppCompatActivity` will use these `fast renderers` by default.

The quickest way to solve this problem is adding the following line of code to your MainActivity class before calling `Forms.Init` to override the `fast renderers`:

```
Forms.SetFlags("UseLegacyRenderers");
```

You can also write a custom renderer of Button to improve the behavior.

I uploaded a sample project [here](https://github.com/XfHua/Faster-renderer) and you can check it.